# Magento 2: How can I get de locale code?

Tags: magento2, locale

How can i get de locale code in the current shop?

For example es-ES or en-EN.

I tried

```
$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getLocaleCode();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$storeId =  $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
     */
    $localeCode =  $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/locale/code', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);
```

Hope This helps.

Comment: Kindly thumb up and accept the ans if it worked.

Comment: It is already accepted